# If I connect to SQL Server through network it does not connect?

Tags: sql-server

If I connect the system through network `server\sqlexpress` it does not connect, if I remove `\sqlexpress` it connects. I want to connect using `server\sqlexpress` please give me a solution.

Comment: Well, what *instance* do you really have on your system? Did you install the default, unnamed instance - then you connect to it using `.` or `(local)`. Did you install the SQL Server Express with the named instance of `SQLEXPRESS`, then you connect to your server with `.\sqlexpress` or `(local)\Sqlexpress`. It's not such much about what you *want* - but about what you actually *have* on your system!

Comment: If i connect in my system it connects by .\sqlexpress. I connected through other system it does not connects

Comment: SQL Server **Express** does **not** allow remote connections by default - [it can be enabled to do so](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2005/05/05/415084.aspx), however!

Comment: i have enabled remote connections. Without using .\sqlexpress it connects from other system but if i use .\sqlexpress it does not connect. But in my system both the command are connecting

Answer (score 0):

When you have installed your Sql Server, you have defined a name of instance.

The name of instance you provided, I think, not include the "sqlexpress" term, so, your string "server\sqlexpress" is not accepted.

Comment: While installing i give the named instance only. in the textbox i will give sqlexpress